# datagridview displaying data repeatedly

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Good day everyone,I am currently making a windows application in c#,I am trying to display my data from my database to the datagridview,my problem is whenever I add a second data to my database using the gui, my datagridview display the existing data that already displayed,I know it is just a small problem but I have not found where the problem is. Thankyou everyone.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: pls. learn... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to re-populate your datagridview datasoruce again after adding data to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset data grid view data source to nothing. And again assign data source.

```
datagrid.DataSource = null;
datagrid.DataSource = dataSource;
```